# Change values on array of arrays (matrix) with function, on C language

Tags: c, function, matrix

I know that for swapping, changing any data passed as arguments to a function that change the data, in C, we actually need to pass the address of the data to be changed. As for normal data or arrays, it's quite easy, but when it comes about array of arrays, I got stuck, and confused.

In my main I had:

```
int p[20][21];
FILE *f;
f=fopen("intro.txt","rt");

m=0;
n=0;

while( ( c=getc(f) ) != EOF ) 
{
    if(c==' ')
    {
        p[m][n]=0;
        n++;
    }
    else if(c=='^')
    {
        pa[m][n]=5;
        n++;
    }
    else if(c=='*')
    {
        p[m][n]=1;
        n++;
    }
    else if(c=='#')
    { 
        p[m][n]=-1;
        m++;
        n=0;
    }
}
```

This block of code is creating my matrix, according to my txt file. This is, in my project, the step of initializing matrix that will be use after.

After my matrix is created, I need to change some values on various positions in my matrix, like:

```
p1m=0;
p1n=0;

p2m=19;
p2n=20;

p[p1m][p1n]=5;
p[p2m][p2n]=5;
```

But I need to do this, within a function, pass my matrix to the function, and get my matrix changed within my main.

I've tried to set the parameter in the function as:

```
void myfunc(int* p[20][21])
```

and access it in main like:

```
(myfunc &p[20][21])
```

Or

```
void myfunc(int** p[20][21])
```

But I guess I'm not doing it in the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Say this:

```
void myfunc(int p[20][21])
{
    p[2][3] = 8;  // for example
}
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    int p[20][21];
    myfunc(p);
    return p[2][3];
}
```

Comment: yes, i'm doing exactly that, assigning new values on some matrix elements, but, doing that on a function, calling the function in main, just like:   myfunc(p20][21])  won't work in C.

Answer (score 0):

As Kerrek points out, you can simply pass in the array name all by itself. No different from a normal array.

When you compile, down in the guts, the array 'p' is assigned an address and where-ever p is called, it uses that address. It's kind of treated like a pointer. So if you want to dink around with an array inside of a function, even a 2D array, you can simply call:

```
int myArray[x];
int my2DArray[x][y];
myfunc(myArray, my2DArray);
```

The function is given two addresses and it's up to the function to know how to properly interact with the data behind them.